# numerical coding of mutated residues and positions

Tags: python, alignment

I'm writing a python program which has to compute a **numerical coding of mutated residues and positions** of a set of strings.These strings are protein sequences.These sequences are stored in fasta format file and each protein sequence is separated by comma.The sequence lengths may differ for different protein.In this  I tried to find the position and sequence which are mutated.
I used following code for getting this.

```
a = 'AGFESPKLH'
b = 'KGFEHMKLH'
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i] != b[i]:
     print i, a[i], b[i]
```

But I want the sequence file as *input file*.The following figure will tell about my project.In this figure first box represents alignment of input file sequences.The last box represents the output file.
How can I do this in Python? 
please help me.
Thank you for everyone for your time.

example:

```
input file

MTAQDD,MTAQDD,MTSQED,MTAQDD,MKAQHD




        positions  1  2  3  4  5  6                         1  2  3  4  5  6

protein sequence1  M  T  A  Q  D  D                            T  A     D

protein sequence2  M  T  A  Q  D  D                            T  A     D

protein sequence3  M  T  S  Q  E  D                            T  S     E

protein sequence4  M  T  A  Q  D  D                            T  A     D

protein sequence5  M  K  A  Q  H  D                            K  A     H


     PROTEIN SEQUENCE ALIGNMENT                          DISCARD NON-VARIABLE REGION
```

---

```
        positions  2  2  3  3  5  5  5

protein sequence1  T     A     D   

protein sequence2  T     A     D   

protein sequence3  T        S     E

protein sequence4  T     A     D   

protein sequence5     K  A           H

   MUTATED RESIDUE IS SPLITED TO SEPARATE COLUMN
```

---

Output file should be like this:

```
position+residue   2T  2K  3A  3S  5D  5E  5H

       sequence1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0

       sequence2   1   0   1   0   1   0   0

       sequence3   1   0   0   1   0   1   0

       sequence4   1   0   1   0   1   0   0

       sequence5   0   1   1   0   0   0   1

    (RESIDUES ARE CODED 1 IF PRESENT, 0 IF ABSENT)
```

Comment: I improved formatting -- however, I'm not sure about the hor. lines -- are they part of the formatting or do they belong to the input file ??? As of now, I made them part of the formatting

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. This is the first time I am using stackoverflow. Thank you @TheodrosZelleke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to work with tabular data, consider [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
from pandas import *

data = 'MTAQDD,MTAQDD,MTSQED,MTAQDD,MKAQHD'

df = DataFrame([list(row) for row in data.split(',')])

print DataFrame({str(col)+val:(df[col]==val).apply(int) 
        for col in df.columns for val in set(df[col])})
```

*output:*

```
  0M  1K  1T  2A  2S  3Q  4D  4E  4H  5D
0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
2   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1
3   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
4   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1
```

---

If you want to drop the columns with all ones:

```
print df.select(lambda x: not df[x].all(), axis = 1)    

   1K  1T  2A  2S  4D  4E  4H
0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
3   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
4   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks root, works nicely. But I didn't get  "print df.select(lambda x: not df[x].all(), axis = 1)"that's for removing the columns with all one.

Comment: @user2005075 -- from your exmple, it seemed to me that you didn't want the cols where all the values were the same...like `0M,3Q,5D` but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: what you guessed is right, what I am saying is "print df.select(lambda x: not df[x].all(), axis = 1)" not working

Comment: @user2005075 -- It should, as I tested it, but you have to do first transformation first and assign it to a var like: `df = DataFrame({str(col)+val:(df[col]==val).apply(int) 
        for col in df.columns for val in set(df[col])})` and then apply the second,

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
ls = 'MTAQDD,MTAQDD,MTSQED,MTAQDD,MKAQHD'.split(',')

pos = [set(enumerate(x, 1)) for x in ls]
alle = sorted(set().union(*pos))

print '\t'.join(str(x) + y for x, y in alle)
for p in pos:
    print '\t'.join('1' if key in p else '0' for key in alle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protein_sequence = "MTAQDDSYSDGKGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN,MTSQEDSYSDGKGNYNTIMPGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIMPGAVFQLN,MKAQDDSYSDGRGNYNTIYLGAVFQLQ,MKSQEDSYSDGRGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIYPGAVFQLN,MTAQEDSYSDGRGEYNTIYLGAVFQLQ,MTAQDDSYSDGKGDYNTIMLGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGEYNTIYLGAVFQLN"

#Parse the file
proteins = protein_sequence.split(",")
#For each protein sequence remove the duplicates
proteins = map(lambda x:"".join(set(list(x))), proteins)

#Create result
result = []
key_set = ['T', 'K', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'D', 'N', 'E', 'Y', 'M', 'L', 'P', 'N', 'Q']
for protein in proteins:
    local_dict = dict(zip(key_set, [0] * len(key_set)))
    #Split the protein in amino acid
    components = list(protein)
    for amino_acid in components:
        local_dict[amino_acid] = 1
    result.append((protein, local_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) function `get_dummies` to do most of the hard work:

```
In [11]: s # a pandas Series (DataFrame's column)
Out[11]: 
0    T
1    T
2    T
3    T
4    K
Name: 1

In [12]: pd.get_dummies(s, prefix=s.name, prefix_sep='')
Out[12]: 
   1K  1T
0   0   1
1   0   1
2   0   1
3   0   1
4   1   0
```

To put your data into a DataFrame you could use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(list, 'MTAQDD,MTAQDD,MTSQED,MTAQDD,MKAQHD'.split(',')))

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  M  T  A  Q  D  D
1  M  T  A  Q  D  D
2  M  T  S  Q  E  D
3  M  T  A  Q  D  D
4  M  K  A  Q  H  D
```

And to find those columns which have differing values:

```
In [21]: (df.ix[0] != df).any()
Out[21]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
```

Putting this all together:

```
In [31]: I = df.columns[(df.ix[0] != df).any()]

In [32]: J = (pd.get_dummies(df[i], prefix=df[i].name, prefix_sep='') for i in I)

In [33]: df[[]].join(J)
Out[33]: 
   1K  1T  2A  2S  4D  4E  4H
0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
3   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
4   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
```