# inputting and aligning protein sequence

Tags: input, python-2.7, alignment, pandas, biopython

I have a script for finding mutated positions in protein sequence.The following script will do this.

```
import pandas as pd #data analysis python module
data =     'MTAQDDSYSDGKGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN,MTSQEDSYSDGKGNYNTIMPGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIMPGAVFQLN,MKAQDDSYSDGRGNYNTIYLGAVFQLQ,MKSQEDSYSDGRGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIYPGAVFQLN,MTAQEDSYSDGRGEYNTIYLGAVFQLQ,MTAQDDSYSDGKGDYNTIMLGAVFQLN,MTAQDDSYSDGRGEYNTIYLGAVFQLN' #protein sequences

df = pd.DataFrame(map(list,data.split(',')))

I = df.columns[(df.ix[0] != df).any()] 

J = [pd.get_dummies(df[i], prefix=df[i].name+1, prefix_sep='') for i in I] 

print df[[]].join(J)
```

Here I gave the data(hard coded) ie, input protein sequences .Normally in an application user has to give the input sequences ie, I mean soft coding.
Also here alignment is not done.I read biopython tutorial and i got following script,but I don't know how to add these scripts to above one.

```
from Bio import AlignIO
alignment = AlignIO.read("c:\python27\proj\data1.fasta", "fasta")
print alignment
```

How can I do these 
What I have tried :

```
>>> import sys

>>> import pandas as pd

>>> from Bio import AlignIO

>>> data=sys.stdin.read()
    MTAQDDSYSDGKGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN
    MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN
    MTSQEDSYSDGKGNYNTIMPGAVFQLN
    MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIMPGAVFQLN
    MKAQDDSYSDGRGNYNTIYLGAVFQLQ
    MKSQEDSYSDGRGDYNTIYLGAVFQLN
    MTAQDDSYSDGRGDYNTIYPGAVFQLN
    MTAQEDSYSDGRGEYNTIYLGAVFQLQ
    MTAQDDSYSDGKGDYNTIMLGAVFQLN
    MTAQDDSYSDGRGEYNTIYLGAVFQLN
    ^Z
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(map(list,data.split(',')))
>>> I=df.columns[(df.ix[0]!=df).any()]
>>> J=[pd.get_dummies(df[i],prefix=df[i].name+1,prefix_sep='')for i in I]
>>> print df[[]].join(J)
```

But it is giving empty DataFrame as output.

I also tried following, but i don't know how to load these sequences into my script

```
while 1:
 var=raw_input("Enter your sequence here:")
 print "you entered ",var
```

Please help me.

Comment: for the third code snippet: make sure that data is comma separated and  not space or new line separated, or change `data.split(',')` to e.g `data.split('\n')`

Comment: I recognise [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639825/protein-sequence-coding/14641252#14641252) (!)

Answer (score 1):

When you read in data via:

```
sys.stdin.read()
```

Sequences  are separating using `'\n'` rather than `','` (printing `data` would confirm whether this is the case, it *may* be system dependent), so you should split using this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(list,data.split('\n')))
```

*A good way to check this kind of thing is to go through it line by line, where you would see that `df` was a one row DataFrame (which then propagates to make `I` empty).*

Aside: what a [well written piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639825/protein-sequence-coding/14641252#14641252) you are using! :)